# Moved site, but page not loading properly, script or css error

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, display

Good day, just moved site, but having script or css error. updated the nameservers. My other sites that i moved are fine, but this one had issues.

Correctly displaying on my old host Godaddy  http://www.olivetreeitaly.com/index.html

How site looks now on new host A2 Hosting http://olivetreememorial.com/

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like it is loading scripts with the same names, but the scripts themselves are different. On the sources tab of the dev tools, I see, `css/style.css?ver=1.1` on both sites, but they are serving two completely different scripts. It seems like there were some issues copying the scripts to the new server. Also, the `sass` folders are serving completely different scripts.

Comment: The stylesheets are completely different on the two websites. The one that works is 82 kb, the one that doesn't 416kb. Did you mix up the stylesheets from another website by any chance. There is no errors, just your styles don't match your HTML structure.

Comment: Thank you! that was it style.css.map files were missing